# CORS error on HTTP calls in angular-universal (server side)

Tags: angular, cors, angular-universal

I'm using angular universal and generating HTTP requests to the server. My server is located on another domain (api.mysite.com) with CORS settings.

It works perfect on the browser (because www.mysite.com is permitted), but on the server side when the call is done I get a CORS error because the `Origin` is `http://<server ip>:<port>`.

When I try to set the origin via an HTTP interceptor, I get an error `Refused to set unsafe header "Origin"`...

Anyone?

Comment: this is a backend question, not front. What language is the back in? please provide code.

Comment: It's angular-universal running on node.js/express server

Comment: Do you mean that you get a cors issue during server side rendering? Not once the page is loaded in browser? So you get the error you mentioned on the **server** console? And please provide the error message you get

Comment: @David exactly. And I get the error I defined on my api server for when a CORS error occur

Answer (score 3):

CORS is usually configured server side and enforced client side by the browser.

If I understood correctly, what you have here is not a classic CORS issue, as it looks like it is your api server trying to enforce CORS policy (i.e. denying clients with the wrong origin).

Setting the `Origin` header client side is not allowed, as it is handled by the browser. If any js client could set the `Origin` header, CORS mechanism would provide no benefit at all.

I'd say either configure your api server to allow access to the node js server with your custom mechanism, or don't check the `Origin` header  server side and let the browser do it client side, aka the normal way.