# Angular Universal does not wait for api/http request before render

Tags: .net, angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, prerender

I have a brand new angular universal project that seems to pretender all the HTML (which is good).
However, I am trying to make an API call to my .NET server which is a standard API build with the weatherforecast API.

The API calls and it works great, but it only happens after my web app has switched from pre render to csr. see example 1.

**Example 1**

[image]

if I disable javascript on the page this is what I get

[image]

and this is the HTML code

```
  <div style="padding: 5rem">
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    <h2>{{ this.SampleMessage }}</h2>
    <div *ngFor="let product of weather$ | async">
      <p>{{ this.product.summary }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

**app.component.ts**

```
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'ModernaMediaAngular';
  text:string = "test"

  weather$: Observable<any>;
  SampleMessage="Example of Angular Async Pipe";    
  
  constructor(private as: AppService, ) {}

  async ngOnInit() {
    await this.getWeatherAsyncPipe();
    //non async
    this.as.getWeather().subscribe( res =>
      {
        this.text = res[0].date;
        console.log("got resolution");
        console.log(res);
        console.log(this.text);
      }
    );


  }
  public async getWeatherAsyncPipe() {    
        this.SampleMessage="Example of Angular Async Pipe";    
        this.weather$ = await this.as.getWeatherAsync();    
        console.log(this.weather$);
      }    
}
```

---

**app.service.ts**

```
import { environment } from './../environments/environment';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppService {
  public waeatherUrl = environment.url + '/api/weatherForecast/get'
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getWeather() : Observable<object> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders(
      {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : 'http://localhost:4200'
    }
      );
    var x = this.http.get(this.waeatherUrl, {headers: headers}).pipe();
    console.log(x);
    return x;
  }

  public getWeatherAsync():Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.waeatherUrl);    
  }
}
```

---

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserStateInterceptor } from './interceptors/browserstate.interceptor';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { TransferHttpCacheModule } from '@nguniversal/common'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }),
    TransferHttpCacheModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app.server.module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule, ServerTransferStateModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
    ServerTransferStateModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppServerModule {}
```

---

**main.ts**

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
  console.log("DOMCONTENTLOADED");
});
```

---

I also get what I think is a cors error whenever the prerendering tries to fetch from the API.

```
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 66.3 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 141 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.css, styles.css.map (styles) 118 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 2.8 MB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2021-03-15T14:26:38.903Z - Hash: a20337e49cf8941fcbf6 - Time: 12492ms
Hash: af451acd21594faf190e
Time: 19059ms
Built at: 2021-03-15 15:26:41
      Asset      Size  Chunks                          Chunk Names
    main.js  6.44 MiB    main  [emitted]        [big]  main
main.js.map  6.99 MiB    main  [emitted] [dev]         main
Entrypoint main [big] = main.js main.js.map
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 6.08 MiB [entry] [rendered]

Compiled successfully.
** Angular Universal Live Development Server is listening on http://localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200 **
Observable {
  _isScalar: false,
  source: Observable {
    _isScalar: false,
    source: Observable {
      _isScalar: false,
      source: [Observable],
      operator: [MergeMapOperator]
    },
    operator: FilterOperator { predicate: [Function], thisArg: undefined }
  },
  operator: MapOperator { project: [Function], thisArg: undefined }
}

Observable {
  _isScalar: false,
  source: Observable {
    _isScalar: false,
    source: Observable {
      _isScalar: false,
      source: [Observable],
      operator: [MergeMapOperator]
    },
    operator: FilterOperator { predicate: [Function], thisArg: undefined }
  },
  operator: MapOperator { project: [Function], thisArg: undefined }
}

ERROR HttpErrorResponse {
  headers: HttpHeaders {
    normalizedNames: Map {},
    lazyUpdate: null,
    headers: Map {}
  },
  status: 0,
  statusText: 'Unknown Error',
  url: 'https://localhost:5001/api/weatherForecast/get',
  ok: false,
  name: 'HttpErrorResponse',
  message: 'Http failure response for https://localhost:5001/api/weatherForecast/get: 0 Unknown Error',
  error: ProgressEvent {
    type: 'error',
    target: XMLHttpRequest {
      onloadstart: null,
      onprogress: null,
      onabort: null,
      onerror: null,
      onload: null,
      ontimeout: null,
      onloadend: null,
      _listeners: [Object],
      onreadystatechange: null,
      _anonymous: undefined,
      readyState: 4,
      response: null,
      responseText: '',
      responseType: 'text',
      responseURL: '',
      status: 0,
      statusText: '',
      timeout: 0,
      upload: [XMLHttpRequestUpload],
      _method: 'GET',
      _url: [Url],
      _sync: false,
      _headers: [Object],
      _loweredHeaders: [Object],
      _mimeOverride: null,
      _request: null,
      _response: null,
      _responseParts: null,
      _responseHeaders: null,
      _aborting: null,
      _error: null,
      _loadedBytes: 0,
      _totalBytes: 0,
      _lengthComputable: false
    },
    currentTarget: XMLHttpRequest {
      onloadstart: null,
      onprogress: null,
      onabort: null,
      onerror: null,
      onload: null,
      ontimeout: null,
      onloadend: null,
      _listeners: [Object],
      onreadystatechange: null,
      _anonymous: undefined,
      readyState: 4,
      response: null,
      responseText: '',
      responseType: 'text',
      responseURL: '',
      status: 0,
      statusText: '',
      timeout: 0,
      upload: [XMLHttpRequestUpload],
      _method: 'GET',
      _url: [Url],
      _sync: false,
      _headers: [Object],
      _loweredHeaders: [Object],
      _mimeOverride: null,
      _request: null,
      _response: null,
      _responseParts: null,
      _responseHeaders: null,
      _aborting: null,
      _error: null,
      _loadedBytes: 0,
      _totalBytes: 0,
      _lengthComputable: false
    },
    lengthComputable: false,
    loaded: 0,
    total: 0
  }
}

ERROR HttpErrorResponse {
  headers: HttpHeaders {
    normalizedNames: Map {},
    lazyUpdate: null,
    headers: Map {}
  },
  status: 0,
  statusText: 'Unknown Error',
  url: 'https://localhost:5001/api/weatherForecast/get',
  ok: false,
  name: 'HttpErrorResponse',
  message: 'Http failure response for https://localhost:5001/api/weatherForecast/get: 0 Unknown Error',
  error: ProgressEvent {
    type: 'error',
    target: XMLHttpRequest {
      onloadstart: null,
      onprogress: null,
      onabort: null,
      onerror: null,
      onload: null,
      ontimeout: null,
      onloadend: null,
      _listeners: [Object],
      onreadystatechange: null,
      _anonymous: undefined,
      readyState: 4,
      response: null,
      responseText: '',
      responseType: 'text',
      responseURL: '',
      status: 0,
      statusText: '',
      timeout: 0,
      upload: [XMLHttpRequestUpload],
      _method: 'GET',
      _url: [Url],
      _sync: false,
      _headers: [Object],
      _loweredHeaders: [Object],
      _mimeOverride: null,
      _request: null,
      _response: null,
      _responseParts: null,
      _responseHeaders: null,
      _aborting: null,
      _error: null,
      _loadedBytes: 0,
      _totalBytes: 0,
      _lengthComputable: false
    },
    currentTarget: XMLHttpRequest {
      onloadstart: null,
      onprogress: null,
      onabort: null,
      onerror: null,
      onload: null,
      ontimeout: null,
      onloadend: null,
      _listeners: [Object],
      onreadystatechange: null,
      _anonymous: undefined,
      readyState: 4,
      response: null,
      responseText: '',
      responseType: 'text',
      responseURL: '',
      status: 0,
      statusText: '',
      timeout: 0,
      upload: [XMLHttpRequestUpload],
      _method: 'GET',
      _url: [Url],
      _sync: false,
      _headers: [Object],
      _loweredHeaders: [Object],
      _mimeOverride: null,
      _request: null,
      _response: null,
      _responseParts: null,
      _responseHeaders: null,
      _aborting: null,
      _error: null,
      _loadedBytes: 0,
      _totalBytes: 0,
      _lengthComputable: false
    },
    lengthComputable: false,
    loaded: 0,
    total: 0
  }
}
```

but no errors in console:

[image]

In **startup.cs** in my .NET 5 project I have configured cors:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "ModernaMediaDotNet", Version = "v1" });
        });
    services.AddCors();
}
```

and in public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors(x => x
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) // allow any origin
            );
```

Comment: Could it be that the rendering server cannot access the API?

Comment: @RobinDijkhof That seems like the problem, but it's weird as the're is literally no cors policy and the car part of the application are able to access the api

Comment: Does that help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50051943/1160794

Comment: @David Thank you! I have tried completely disabling cors and allowing anything, yet it doesn't seem to accept the request from SSR engine, only the CSR. You can see my policy at the end of the question

Comment: Can you make a call without https to see if it works (if your API accept http)? And try to make the https call with curl from your universal server machine?

Comment: @David That worked! if you're able to write a good explanation why this happens I'll give you the bounty :) Had to remove the 's' from https:// in my environment variables for the API url.

Comment: Did the curl call (with https) work from the machine?

Comment: @David havent tested that, but as i mentioned in the question I am able to retrieve the data through an API call when doing CSR, but not with SSR

Comment: I understand, but it would have just given more info as to 'why'. I'll write an answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I once had the same problem on our test environment, and it was due to the fact that we were using a self signed certificate, which node did not like.

We ended up adding the line below in `server.ts` so that node disables TLS validation.

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';
```

**Note** This is unsecure ([documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_tls_reject_unauthorized_value)) and you should not use this in prod (where you should have valid certificates).

Another option would be to only make http calls when you are server side, which  you could implement using a `HttpInterceptor`

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful. Can you give more details about how set valid certificates?

Comment: Thank you. Helped me a lot. I was all day long front this issue.
Now, I need to publish angular app using Angular universal.

Comment: "nother option would be to only make http calls when you are server side, which you could implement using a HttpInterceptor" How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Your app probably needs to wrap the API call in a zone macro task.

1. npm install [`@bespunky/angular-zen`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bespunky/angular-zen)
2. Import `RouterXModule` (`.forRoot()` or `.forChild()` according to your module).
3. Have your component/service extend the `RouteAware` class.
4. Wrap your observable in a call to [`this.resolveInMacroTask()`](https://bs-angular-zen.web.app/docs/zen/injectables/RouteAware.html#resolveInMacroTask).

> You could do it manually, but `RouteAware` takes care of everything ***and*** gives you additional benefits.

### More

[Docs (See the *Angular Universal* section)](https://bs-angular-zen.web.app/docs/zen/additional-documentation/routerxmodule/routeaware-(abstract).html)

[Live example using `RouteAware`](https://bs-angular-zen.web.app/RouterX%20Module/Route%20Aware%20Resolves)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however the approach taken should work fluidly even without another dependency.

Comment: Then I suggest you take a look at the implementation of `resolveInMacroTask()`. You could implement it yourself: https://github.com/BeSpunky/angular-zen/blob/530225fc9fe19f607300b778a06f39a341009992/projects/bespunky/angular-zen/router-x/services/route-aware.service.ts#L211

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, use a resolver in your route module, that will fix it, happy coding!

```js
  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {
    this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(({ animes }) => {
      this.animeList = animes;
    });
  }
```