# how to call a http api request in ssr

Tags: angular, api, server-side-rendering

On angular 11, I installed angular universal for ssr.
I would like to call a request from an API to display products and I want it to also be referenced for seo.

in the app-root tag I have the header and footer tags but not the products.

how can i solve this, please  ?

Comment: Your question is missing information. Does your api call trigger successfully on the client but not on the server? is there an error? As this is a common problem with Universal, I'm guessing you're server doesn't wait for the call to finish. Check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66699719/4371525

Answer (score 0):

there are no error.
I see that there is only one call to the API, it is on the client side.

I don't understand why I don't have the 2 calls to the API (client + server)