# Angular SSR does not wait for SEO when using reverse proxy location for Node Api in Nginx

Tags: angular, angular-universal

```
server {
    listen 5000;
    listen [::]:5000;
    server_name localhost;
    root E:\NG9B2C\B2C\dist\B2C\browser;
  
    http2_max_field_size 64k;
    http2_max_header_size 512k;
  
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
    
    
    location /YTB/api {
             
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8073/YTB/api/;   
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1600;
        proxy_send_timeout 1600;
        proxy_read_timeout 1600;
        send_timeout 1600;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
```

When I directly hit the api url : http://localhost:8073/YTB/api/...  - the SEO works and is properly rendered on the page source. But when I route it through a reverse proxy : http://localhost:4000/YTB/api/... , the SEO content does not wait.

Comment: Could it be that the normal endpoint returns very fast, while your proxy takes more time? Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66699719/4371525

Comment: proxy is much faster than normal endpoint. But not able to understand why Angular SSR does not wait for the proxy to return response from the api while it waits for the normal endpoint.

Comment: All I get is a proxy location / rendered page souce , but not of /YTB/api