# SSR is not working on project build with angular 11

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, angular11

In my application,
I fetching HTML data from the API and render it,
but when I trying to do view the source after building the project.
I a not able to see that page content in that.
Tried multiple things for that but didn't work.

what should I do about that?
here I attached angular.json and package.json let me know if any changes are there.

***angular.json***

```
{"$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "Siteuser": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular": {
          "component": {
            "inlineStyle": true,
            "spec": false
          },
          "module": {
            "spec": true
          }
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "aot": true,
            "outputPath": "dist/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/sitemap.xml",
              "src/robots.txt"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/scss/style.scss",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "staging": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
                }
              ],
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "qa": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.qa.ts"
                }
              ],
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "bundle",
                  "name": "main",
                  "maximumWarning": "110kb",
                  "maximumError": "120kb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Siteuser:build",
            "port": 5067,
            "host": "0.0.0.0"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ng:build:production"
            },
            "staging": {
              "browserTarget": "ng:build:staging"
            },
            "qa": {
              "browserTarget": "ng:build:qa"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Siteuser:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/scss/style.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "sourceMap": false,
              "optimization": true
            },
            "staging": {
              "outputHashing": "media",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
                }
              ],
              "sourceMap": false,
              "optimization": true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Siteuser-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "ng:build:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "ng:build:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "Siteuser",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "e959a028-a0c4-47b5-b213-83c1fc414871"
  }
}
```

***package.json***

```
{
  "name": "siteuser",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start-scanner": "ng serve && sonar-scanner",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "prod": "ng build --prod && ng run Siteuser:server:staging && node dist/server/main.js",
    "staging": "ng build --configuration=staging && ng run Siteuser:server:staging && node dist/server/main.js",
    "qa": "ng build --prod --configuration=qa --aot --buildOptimizer --commonChunk --vendorChunk --optimization --progress",
    "compile:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server",
    "optimizecss": "gulp --gulpfile optimize-css.gulpfile.js",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run Siteuser:server:production --bundleDependencies all"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.5",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/animations": "11.2.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "11.2.6",
    "@angular/common": "11.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "11.2.6",
    "@angular/core": "11.2.6",
    "@angular/forms": "11.2.6",
    "@angular/material": "11.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "11.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "11.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-server": "11.2.6",
    "@angular/router": "11.2.6",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^3.7.3",
    "@ng-toolkit/universal": "^1.1.21",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^11.2.1",
    "@schematics/angular": "^11.2.5",
    "@types/jquery": "3.3.22",
    "@types/node": "10.1.4",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "4.3.1",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "3.1.3",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-brotli": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-filter": "^6.0.0",
    "gulp-gzip": "^1.4.2",
    "gulp-imagemin": "5.0.3",
    "gulp-purify-css": "^0.1.0",
    "jquery": "3.4.1",
    "js2xmlparser": "^4.0.1",
    "jsontoxml": "^1.0.1",
    "line-awesome": "1.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ngx-avatar": "^4.0.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^4.3.0",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^3.3.5",
    "ngx-skeleton-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "ngx-ui-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "popper.js": "1.14.6",
    "promise-polyfill": "^8.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.6",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.6",
    "sweetalert2": "7.33.1",
    "ts-loader": "4.2.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "tslint-sonarts": "1.9.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.5",
    "@angular/cli": "11.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "11.2.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "11.2.6",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^11.2.1",
    "@types/express": "4.17.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "source-map-explorer": "^2.5.2",
    "ts-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "ts-node": "7.0.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "4.0.7",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Some API calls should be manually wrapped in zone macro tasks to have the server understand it must wait for their completion. Check this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66699719/4371525

Answer (score 0):

placing the api call in route resolver should work in your case. But the draw back is the load time increases.

ref: https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-angular-route-resolvers-by-example